# Changing an NSWindow border color

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to change the border color around my app's NSWindow.

Does anyone know where the window border gets drawn, and how do I change the color/override the method to draw the border?

I've noticed that Tweetbot does this:

[image: Regular border vs Tweetbot border]

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark here: what if you call `[self.window.contentView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];`, and see if it eliminates the border entirely? From that point you could just draw your own.

Comment: @sudorm-rf no luck here :/

Comment: Yep, I thought that wouldn't work. The main issue here is that `NSWindow` actually draws this border outside of the main content using private CGS functions. I can't seem to remember any way to remove this unless you use a borderless window.

Comment: @sudorm-rf It looks like the contentView's superview is something called an NSThemeFrame. http://parmanoir.com/Custom_NSThemeFrame I'm guessing thats where the border gets drawn, but not sure.

Comment: Nope, actually it's outside of the view hierarchy, from what I've determined.

Comment: @sudorm-rf ah ya you're right, just overwrote the `drawRect` in NSThemeFrame, still bordered.

Answer (score 2):

From memory, I think Tweetbot have used a full borderless window, and added the window controls themselves, but if you want to let AppKit still handle those details, there's another way. If you set your window to be a textured window, then you can set a custom background NSColor. This NSColor can be an image using `+[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:]`

I knocked this up quickly as an example, just using a solid grey colour as the fill, but you can draw anything you like in this image. Then all you need is to set the class type of your NSWindow to your textured window class.

SLFTexturedWindow.h

```
@interface SLFTexturedWindow : NSWindow
@end
```

SLFTexturedWindow.m

```
#import "SLFTexturedWindow.h"

@implementation SLFTexturedWindow

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)styleMask
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag;
{
    NSUInteger newStyle;
if (styleMask & NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask) {
    newStyle = styleMask;
} else {
    newStyle = (NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask | styleMask);
}

if (self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:newStyle backing:bufferingType defer:flag]) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(windowDidResize:)
                                                     name:NSWindowDidResizeNotification
                                                   object:self];

        [self setBackgroundColor:[self addBorderToBackground]];

        return self;
}

return nil;
}

- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[self addBorderToBackground]];
}

- (NSColor *)addBorderToBackground
{
    NSImage *bg = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[self frame].size];
    // Begin drawing into our main image
[bg lockFocus];

[[NSColor lightGrayColor] set];
NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0, 0, [bg size].width, [bg size].height));

    [[NSColor blackColor] set];

    NSRect bounds = NSMakeRect(0, 0, [self frame].size.width, [self frame].size.height);
    NSBezierPath *border = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds xRadius:3 yRadius:3];
    [border stroke];

    [bg unlockFocus];

    return [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:bg];  
}

@end
```

Comment: Actually it looks like this leads to the window having 2 borders, a black on the inside and a gray one on the outside. http://cl.ly/image/201s0X0S1F3Q

Comment: Yes, it seems you're right. Sorry about that, I wasn't able to see the grey border, even looking closely (combination of bad eyesight and retina display). It looks like you'll have to use the borderless window method and draw the titlebar yourself

Comment: Ya I have a retina as well, i had to take it in to photoshop to check for the other border :P Thanks for the help.